# How can I format decimal property to currency?

Tags: c#, decimal, currency

I want to format a decimal value as a currency value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Properties can return anything they want to, but it's going to need to return the correct type.

```
private decimal _amount;

public string FormattedAmount
{
    get { return string.Format("{0:C}", _amount); }
}
```

Question was asked... what if it was a nullable decimal.

```
private decimal? _amount;

public string FormattedAmount
{
    get
    {
         return _amount == null ? "null" : string.Format("{0:C}", _amount.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the amount is a nullable decimal?

Comment: You can also specify the number of desired decimal places after the letter C, for example, if your value was 12.123 and you only wanted 2 decimal places in the output, you can use String.Format("{0:C2}", _amount.Value. Furthermore, you can specify a IFormatProvider if you want your string to be formatted to a specific culture.

Answer (score 45):

Below would also work, but you cannot put in the getter of a decimal property.  The getter of a decimal property can only return a decimal, for which formatting does not apply.

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m; 
string currencyValue = moneyvalue.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this;

```
  string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-SG", false), "{0:c0}", 123423.083234);
```

It will convert 123423.083234 to $1,23,423 format.

Answer (score 10):

You can create an extension method. I find this to be a good practice as you may need to lock down a currency display regardless of the browser setting. For instance you may want to display $5,000.00 always instead of 5 000,00 $
(#CanadaProblems)

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static string ToCurrency(this decimal decimalValue)
    {
        return $"{decimalValue:C}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use String.Format, see the code [via [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/format-a-string-as-currency-in-c/)]:

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
Console.WriteLine(html);
// Output: $1,921.39
```

See also:

- [decimal (C# Reference) at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)
- [Decimal parse for currency](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0040__Data-Type/Decimalparseforcurrency.htm)

Answer (score 4):

You can now use string interpolation and expression bodied properties in C# 6.

```
private decimal _amount;

public string FormattedAmount => $"{_amount:C}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your returned format will be limited by the return type you declare.  So yes, you can declare the property as a string and return the formatted value of something.  In the "get" you can put whatever data retrieval code you need.  So if you need to access some numeric value, simply put your return statement as:

```
    private decimal _myDecimalValue = 15.78m;
    public string MyFormattedValue
    {
        get { return _myDecimalValue.ToString("c"); }
        private set;  //makes this a 'read only' property.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A decimal type can not contain formatting information.  You can create another property, say `FormattedProperty` of a string type that does what you want.

Answer (score -2):

In My case, I have to convert it into decimal as above mentioned I used to string Format method and then parse it to decimal and it works fine for me here is the example.

**public decimal Amount;**

**public decimal_amount;**

So I assigned values like this:

**Amount = decimal.Parse(String.Format("{0:C}", _amount))**

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. It's currency so why would the value be in a DatetimeOffset object?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out after your comment I realized I used decimal for Amount and used Datetimeoffset for the date field.