# textbox to display currency

Tags: c#, textbox

I am writing my first program and I am using Visual Studio 2013. The project I am working on is for school and is a payroll system. The language we are using is C# and is a windows form application. So far I have achieved the correct output which is great, and even though its not required I would like to display the output in a currency format. Any guidance or direction would be appreciated. I've tried to search stack overflow for my answer, but I feel that many of the answers are above my understanding for I have only been doing this for a week

Here is my code. The user inputs the employees hours worked and pay rate. The output is gross pay, federal withholding (15%) state withholding(5%) and net pay.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add two textboxes together
        Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        Int32 val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        Int32 val3 = val1 * val2;
        // gross pay result
         textBox3.Text = val3.ToString();
        // federal witholdings
        decimal number = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        decimal fW = number * 15 / 100;
        textBox4.Text = fW.ToString();
        // state witholdings
        decimal sW = number * 5 / 100;
        textBox5.Text = sW.ToString();
         //Net pay, defined as gross pay minus taxes
        Int32 val4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        Int32 val5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        Int32 val6 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        Int32 val7 = (val4- (val5 + val6));
        textBox6.Text = val7.ToString();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textbox for price/cash/currency on C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp)

Comment: `textbox5`, `val7`...

Answer (score 2):

You should use the apropiate format string for this:

```
string.Format("{0:C}", val7);
```

See this similar question:

[How can i format decimal property to currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479284/how-can-i-format-decimal-property-to-currency)

Answer (score -1):

```
 textBox6.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", val7);
```