# Format money data table value in c#

Tags: c#, ssis, dts, c#-datatable

Can anyone help in formatting money data type for two columns dynamically?.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ST_367d705c54de4e9e9f890350f933c80b.csproj

{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion


    public void Main()
    {
        string basePath = Dts.Variables["User::VarDirectoryPath"].Value.ToString();

        try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            var delimiter = Dts.Variables["User::VarDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
            A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::VarObject"].Value);

            basePath = Dts.Variables["User::VarDirectoryPath"].Value.ToString();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, (Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName_1"].Value.ToString()
                + Dts.Variables["User::VarDate"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::VarFileExtension_1"].Value.ToString()));

            int i = 0;
            StreamWriter sw = null;

            using (sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dt.Columns[i].ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::VarDelimiter"].Value.ToString());
                }

                sw.WriteLine();

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    object[] array = row.ItemArray;
                    for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    {
                        object val = array[i];
                        if (val == "0")
                            sw.Write(string.Format("#.##", val) + delimiter);
                        else
                            sw.Write(val + delimiter);
                    }

                    sw.WriteLine();
                }

                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string file = string.Format("err_{0}.txt", Dts.Variables["User::VarDate"].Value.ToString());
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(basePath, file), ex.ToString());
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestions? There are 10 columns in the data table and column 3,4,5 need to be formatted with two decimal places and also need to input 0.00 if the value is equal to zero or null.

Comment: What's the data type of those columns? You should convert it to floats or doubles using float.tryparse

Comment: The data type of the columns are decimal(18,2) it defaults to 0 in excel. I need the value of 0.00 for null or "0" value. Also need if the value whole number 529 then it should display as 529.00

Comment: No I mean what's the data type of your object val = array[i]; for those columns? Debug and check. You are assuming they are parsed as strings and if so, you need to parse them to doubles or floats before you do your formatting. Also check string.isNullOrEmpty() to handle the nulls.

Comment: It is passed as decimal for 3,4 and 5.

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong in your code now? It looks fine to me if it's decimal...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i format decimal property to currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479284/how-can-i-format-decimal-property-to-currency)

Comment: I need to format the decimal from 0 to 0.00. If it is 560 then it should display as 560.00

Comment: Ok so you have an example in the answer below. But still there are other errors in your code, such as `if (val == "0")` which assumes val is a string and not a decimal. If you want to make it correct you should do `if (val == 0m)` (<--- prefered) or `if (val.ToString() == "0")`....

Comment: also I would not declare objects, if you want to use not-specific data types you should use `var` instead of `object`. `object` is a specific data type which all other data types derives from... `var` on the other hand is "let the compiler pick the right data type for me".

Comment: Is this code trying to *export* data to a CSV? That's built-in already. Why don't you use a CSV destination specifying a format string or culture?

Comment: Yes, I exporting the data to a CSV

Comment: Even though the formatting is correct when output to CSV it changes to "0".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on formatting decimals:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/da7UoR

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal val1 = 0m;
        decimal val2 = 125580m;


        Console.WriteLine(val1.ToString("0.00"));
        //Output 0.00

        Console.WriteLine(val2.ToString("0.00"));
        //Output 125580.00

        //Money format
        Console.WriteLine(val1.ToString("C"));      
        //Output $0.00

        Console.WriteLine(decimalToFormattedString(val1));
        //Output 0.00

        Console.WriteLine(decimalToFormattedString(val2));
        //Output 125580.00
    }

    public static string decimalToFormattedString(decimal myValue)
    {   
        return myValue.ToString("0.00");
    }
}
```