# functions along a variable on c#

Tags: c#

I am new into programming with c# and I am trying to do a `Console.WriteLine` where I have $ and a variable inside {}, instead of the usual way that is done in c#.
However when I try to add a fuction it does'nt work, because I don't know the correct syntax to do it.

**example (function `Math.round`)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal Euro, Dolar;
            decimal tax = 1.19590m;

            Console.WriteLine("Convert euro into dólar- day 06/05/2018.\nWhat is the amount in euros? ");

            Euro = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Dolar = Euro * tax;

            Console.WriteLine($"The final value is: (Math.Round,2){Dolar} dólars");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need Math.Round(), consider {Dolar:N2} to use composite formatting.

Comment: @HansPassant haha, I was adding that remark to my answer too ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i format decimal property to currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479284/how-can-i-format-decimal-property-to-currency)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where did you read about that syntax... but that should be something like:

```
$"The final value is: {Math.Round(Dolar, 2)} dólars"
```

The parentheses inside the string literal have no special meaning... all the parsed code must be within the brackets for interpolated strings. Think of it as:

```
"The final value is: " + Math.Round(Dolar, 2).ToString() + " dólars"
```

Or

```
var final = Math.Round(Dolar, 2);
$"The final value is: {final} dólars"
```

If you are working with an IDE (Visual Studio, VSCode, etc.) which is coloring the syntax, it should be obvious there (everything inside the brackets is colored as regular code, not as the string)

Also, you don't really need `Math.Round` here, but that wouldn't answer your question :-)

Comment: @LeonardoGuimarães yes

Comment: @LeonardoGuimarães: Between the brackets, you can put any value you want. This includes evaluations (e.g. `$" { 1+2-3 } "`) and methods **which return a value** (no void methods) (e.g. `$" { MyMethodWhichReturnsAValue(1,2,3) } "`).

Comment: Not "any value you want", but for practical purposes, yes, mostly... there is further information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The final value is: {0} dólars", Math.Round(Dolar, 2));
```